# How can I make my Athena SQL query faster

Tags: string, datetime, query-optimization, where-clause, presto

I am running this on AWS Athena based on PrestoDB. My original plan was to query data 3 months in the past to analyze that data. However, even the query times for 2 hours in the past takes more than 30 minutes, at which point the Query times out. Is there any more efficient way for the query to be carried out?

```
SELECT column1, dt, column 2
FROM database1
WHERE date_parse(dt, '%Y%m%d%H%i%s') > CAST(now() - interval '1' hour AS timestamp)
```

The date column is recorded in the form of a string YYYYmmddhhmmss

Comment: What is the format of your data files? Is the data compressed? Are you using partitioned data? These are all important factors that can impact the performance (AND the cost!) of Amazon Athena. See: [Analyzing Data in S3 using Amazon Athena | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/)

Comment: this defnitely looks like the issue happening due to small files in the source. Can you confirm the average file size in source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Likely, the problem is that the query applies a function on the column being filtered. This is inefficient, becase the database needs to convert the entire column before it is able to filter it. One says that this predicate is *non-SARGable*.

Your primary effort should go into fixing your data model and store dates as `date`s rather than strings.

That said, the string format that you are using to represent dates still makes it possible to use direct filtering. The idea is to convert the filter value to the target string format (rather than converting the column value to a date):

```
where dt > date_format(now() - interval '1' hour, '%Y%m%d%H%i%s')
```

Comment: Before changing all your data you can test whether this would help by running a query like `WHERE dt > '202009141000'`. If using a string comparison with a static value does not speed up the query significantly, don't go rewriting all your data.

Comment: What I'm really saying is that it's unlikely that the problem is that a function is applied to the `dt` column. The suggestion to format the right hand side to match the existing data format is good, and will help, but I suspect it will be marginal at best, Athena's query planner doesn't know anything about the data, and there are no indexes, the filtering is brute force. If the data format is Parquet it could have a small effect because of predicate pushdown, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different factors that influence the time it takes for Athena to execute a query. The amount of data is usually dominates, but other important factors are data format (there's a huge difference between CSV and Parquet for example), and the number of files. In contrast to many other new database situations the complexity of the query is less often an important factor, and your query is very straightforward and is not the problem (it doesn't help that you apply a function in both sides of the `WHERE` condition, but it's not a big deal in Athena since the filtering is brute force and applying a function on each row isn't that big a deal compared to IO in an engine like Athena.

If you provide more information about the number of files, the data format, and so on we can probably help you better, because without that kind of information it could be just about anything. My suspicion is that you have something like a single prefix with tens or hundreds of millions of files – this is the worst possible case for Athena.

When Athena plans a query it lists the table's location on S3. S3's list operation has a page size of 1000, so if there are more files than that Athena will have to list sequentially until it gets the full listing. This cannot be parallelised, and it's also not very fast.

You need to avoid, almost at all cost, having more than 1000 files in the same prefix. If you have more files than that you can add prefixes (directories), because Athena will list S3 as if it was a file system, and parallelise listings of prefixes. A 1000 files each in `table-data/a/`, `table-data/b/`, `table-data/c/` is much better than 3000 files in `table-data/`.

The reason why I suspect it's lots of small files rather than a lot of data is that if it was a lot of data you would probably have said so – and lots of data is actually something Athena is really good at. Ripping though terabytes of data is no problem unless it's a billion tiny files.